# How to find a position of a text programmatically in Monaco editor

Tags: monaco-editor

Is there any way how to calculate the position in monaco editor by having the original string and the index of the beginning and ending of a sub string from the string?

There is a possibility to [find matches API](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.itextmodel.html#findmatches):

```
editor.getModel().findMatches('sub_string')
```

I am wondering if there is any other ways as there can be more than one match and the API method doesn't completely suitable for my current task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an API Method `getPositionAt` (see [here](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.ITextModel.html#getPositionAt))

```js
const position = editor.getModel().getPositionAt(index);
const { lineNumber, column } = position;
```

Comment: Link no longer works. What if you don't have the index and only have a string?

Comment: @cs_pupil the link has been updated, thanks!
In case you only have a string then you should be able to find the index using string operations, like `String.prototype.indexOf()`.

Answer (score 5):

[FindMatches](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.ITextModel.html#findMatches) worked great for me for finding the position of a text programmatically in Monaco editor.

Even if you only have a search string (and no indexes), it should find every match and not only return the starting lineNumber and column positions, but the ending points as well.

```
editor.getModel().findMatches('sub_string', true, false, false, null, true);
```

[FindMatches example return value](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/classes/monaco.editor.FindMatch.html):

[image]